# Lambda Function in python returning configuration error

Tags: python-3.x, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I keep getting this error message from my Lambda Function:

```
Tue Aug 18 21:15:31 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Tue Aug 18 21:15:31 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 502
```

What is I am trying to do is have a user enter two numbers. The lambda function takes those numbers and runs them through a function which references a list. The output is a row from the list containing two numbers, a name, and a default message.
My Lambda function is in Python 3.6 and I am using API gateway using a GET method. List_r5 is a python script with a small list:

```
import json
from math import cos, asin, sqrt
import List_r5

print('Loading function')

#Parse out query string parameters
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    usera_in = event['queryStringParameters']['usera_in']
    userb_in = event['queryStringParameters']['userb_in']

    print('UserA_In=' + usera_in)
    print('UserB_In=' + userb_in)

#Define the function
def dis(us1, ub1, us2, ub2):
    p = 0.017453292519943295
    a = 0.5 - cos((us2-us1)*p)/2 + cos(us1*p)*cos(us2*p) * (1-cos((ub2-ub1)*p)) / 2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))

def clo(database, input):
    return min(database, key=lambda p: dis(v['us'],v['ub'],p['us'],p['ub']))

    coord = {'us': usera_in, 'ub': userb_in}   
    output = clo(List_r5.data, coord)

    sta_output = output['NAME']
    us_output = output['us']
    ub_output = output['ub']

#Body of response object
    gResponse = {}
    gResponse['Sta'] = sta_output
    gResponse['UserA'] = us_output
    gResponse['UserB'] = ub_output
    gResponse['Message'] = 'All good on your end?'


#HTTP response object
    responseObject = {}
    responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
    responseObject['headers'] = {}
    responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(gResponse)

#Return response object
    return responseObject
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that your `clo` function returns `min(database...)` immediately, meaning that the rest of the function, as well as the response object you actually want to return at the end of the function, becomes unreachable.

Comment: @DarthCadeus Thank you. I have edited the code and the clo function is used again for the variable output 5 lines down

Comment: @GK89 could you update your code snippet with the corrected `clo` function?

Comment: @MCI It is updated: it just returns the min value. I run the clo function a few lines down to generate output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything after `def clo. . .` to the end of the snippet is inside the clo function definition, so it will never be executed. Un-indent the code as so

```py
def clo(database, input):
    return min(database, key=lambda p: dis(v['us'],v['ub'],p['us'],p['ub']))

coord = {'us': usera_in, 'ub': userb_in}   
output = clo(List_r5.data, coord)

sta_output = output['NAME']
us_output = output['us']
ub_output = output['ub']

#Body of response object
gResponse = {}
gResponse['Sta'] = sta_output
gResponse['UserA'] = us_output
gResponse['UserB'] = ub_output
gResponse['Message'] = 'All good on your end?'


#HTTP response object
responseObject = {}
responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
responseObject['headers'] = {}
responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(gResponse)

#Return response object
return responseObject
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like an indentation problem. Try indenting the functions dis() and clo() along with its contents.

```
import json
from math import cos, asin, sqrt
import List_r5

print('Loading function')

#Parse out query string parameters
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    usera_in = event['queryStringParameters']['usera_in']
    userb_in = event['queryStringParameters']['userb_in']

    print('UserA_In=' + usera_in)
    print('UserB_In=' + userb_in)

    #Define the function
    def dis(us1, ub1, us2, ub2):
        p = 0.017453292519943295
        a = 0.5 - cos((us2-us1)*p)/2 + cos(us1*p)*cos(us2*p) * (1-cos((ub2-ub1)*p)) / 2
        return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))

    def clo(database, input):
        return min(database, key=lambda p: dis(v['us'],v['ub'],p['us'],p['ub']))

    coord = {'us': usera_in, 'ub': userb_in}   
    output = clo(List_r5.data, coord)

    sta_output = output['NAME']
    us_output = output['us']
    ub_output = output['ub']

#Body of response object
    gResponse = {}
    gResponse['Sta'] = sta_output
    gResponse['UserA'] = us_output
    gResponse['UserB'] = ub_output
    gResponse['Message'] = 'All good on your end?'


#HTTP response object
    responseObject = {}
    responseObject['statusCode'] = 200
    responseObject['headers'] = {}
    responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(gResponse)

#Return response object
    return responseObject
```